# undefined method "each" rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each, erb

I am an error in my view:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
<tbody>
   <% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= invoice.invoiceDate%></td>
       <td><%= invoice.invoiceNumber %></td>
```

Here is my invoice controller index:

```
def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all
end
```

Most posts I've seen about this error are because `@invoices` isn't declared correctly, unlike mine. Anyone have any ideas what else might be wrong??

Thanks!!

Comment: Which view is your above code snippet in?

Comment: Hi - it is in my /task_orders/show view. Basically, I am showing all the invoices that belong to that task order @JKen13579

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using `@invoices` in your show view, you need to actually set `@invoices` in your `show` method, rather than your `index` method. So, add the following code to your controller, and you should be all set.

```
def show
  @invoices = Invoice.all
end
```

Answer (score 4):

> that belong to that task order

You'll be best doing that like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :task_orders

#app/controllers/task_orders_controller.rb
Class TaskOrdersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @task_order = TaskOrder.find params[:id]
      @invoices = @task_order.invoices
   end
end

#app/views/task_orders/show.html.erb
<% for invoice in @invoices do %>
   <%= invoice.something %>
<% end %>
```